# Batching / Framing in Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a `Source[Animal]`, where `Animal` is of 2 types `Cat` and `Dog`. The `source` is something like `dog1, dog2, dog3, cat1, dog4, dog5, cat2, cat3, dog6, dog7, dog8, dog9, dog10, dog11, dog12, cat4 ...`
I'm trying to convert it to the following `Source[Seq[Animal]] - (dog1, dog2, dog3, cat1), (dog4, dog5, cat2), (cat3), (dog6, dog7, dog8), (dog9, dog10, dog11), (dog12, cat4) ...`
How this works is:

- at most 3 dogs per batch, at most 1 cat per batch (alternatively a solution for the following is also fine: at most 4 animals per batch, at most 1 cat per batch)
- a cat must only be the final (aka framing) element in a batch
- also, i can't show speed in an example, but there should be a timeout after which the batch (even if not full and no cat) is still emitted. Something like `groupedWithin(4, FiniteDuration(3, SECONDS))`
- overall order is important and must be maintained

I've been trying stuff with `batchWeighted` and `groupedWithin` but I don't have a proper solution as yet.

One idea I tried was to weigh `Dog` as `1` and `Cat` as `1000` and use `batchWeighted` with `max weight = 1003`, but this won't ensure that `Cat` is always the last batch element... Trying the same with `max weight = 3` always puts `Cat` in separate groups.

If there was a hybrid of `batchWithin` and `takeWhile` (without termination) then it may have solved this use-case.

This is a pretty straight forward thing to solve if its just iterating over a `List`, but being constrained to use `FlowOps` makes it a bit challenging

Edit:
Currently I'm doing the following:

```scala
  .groupedWithin(4, FiniteDuration(4, SECONDS))
  .map(frameBatch(_, Vector(), 0))
  // groupedWithin internally returns a Vector so is fast for indexed operations

  @tailrec
  private def frameBatch(
      items: Seq[Animal],
      result: Vector[Seq[Animal]],
      offset: Int
    ): Vector[Seq[Animal]] = {
    val index = seq.indexWhere(!_.isDog, offset) // assume there's an isDog() for simplicity
    if (index == -1) {
      if (offset == 0) {
        Vector(items)
      } else {
        result :+ items.slice(offset, items.size)
      }
    } else {
      frameBatchAtSyncs(items, result :+ items.slice(offset, index), index + 1)
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is very custom way of "framing" and imo it's best to create a custom `GraphStage` for this. Read this for more info https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html

Comment: @Ivan Stanislavciuc, I do understand that the logic is custom enough to warrant creation of a custom graph stage, but I was hoping I could build this out of existing operators to make implementation easier (lesser code = lesser maintenance). Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this with just the Akka Stream primitives (with a minor detour into Akka Actors):

```
object BatchFrame {
  def batchFrame[M](
    source: Source[Animal, M],
    batchSize: Int,
    interval: FiniteDuration)(implicit system: ActorSystem): Source[Seq[Animal], M] = {

    require(batchSize > 0)

    import system.dispatcher

    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val dataSource = source.map(x => Some(x))
    val (timerRef, timerSource) = Source.actorRef[Any](1, OverflowStrategy.dropHead).map(_ => None).preMaterialize()

    val merged = dataSource.merge(timerSource, eagerComplete = true)

    var nextTick: Option[Cancellable] = None

    def scheduleTick(): Unit = {
      nextTick = nextTick.flatMap { c => c.cancel(); None }
      nextTick = Option(system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(interval, timerRef, None))
    }

    scheduleTick()

    merged.statefulMapConcat{ () =>
      var dogCount = 0
      var frame: List[Animal] = Nil

      def emit(): List[Seq[Animal]] = {
        scheduleTick()
        val ret = List(frame.reverse)
        dogCount = 0
        frame = Nil
        ret
      }

      def emitWith(a: Animal): List[Seq[Animal]] = {
        frame = a :: frame
        emit()
      }

      in: Option[Animal] => {
        in match {
          case Some(cat: Cat) =>
            emitWith(cat)
          case Some(dog: Dog) if dogCount < (batchSize - 1) =>
            dogCount += 1
            frame = dog :: frame
            Nil
          case Some(dog: Dog) =>
            emitWith(dog)
          case _ =>
            emit()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The main trick (which I had to look up and experiment with to prove it to myself) is to prematerialize the timing `Source` so you have the `ActorRef` available for scheduling ticks.

Comment: Thank you! I figured that I'd need a Merged `eagerComplete` source for cancelling, but was stuck on how to get the `ticker` _actually working_. There's some reading up I need to do with this, but it greatly helps me get started.